# Dual boot or virtual box SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, ssd

I'm using my laptop primairily for school and webbrowsing (including several musicplayers and videoplayers) but I want to use dual boot/virtualbox for improved compatability (ms office extensions, occasionally a game (1 installed on my laptop, nothing demanding) netflix (DNS or VPN hiders, due to microsoft silverlight easier with windows)).

I want to use the latest version of ubuntu (no swap due to 8G of RAM) next to windows 8 (probally 50-50 usage ratio).
The laptop that I'm using is a Dell Insperion 5521 with an I7-3537u processor 8G ram and a radeon HD 8730M.

The origin of my question is my SolidStateDrive, I use a 120g SSD drive.
I dont know what is the best method for this kind of setup. Can I use dual boot safely (with proper disk partitioning) due to constantly writing and erasing a specific part of the SSD as a effect of the partitioning. Or is it recommended to make the partitions for the Operating Systems as small as possible and therefore create one big data partition used by both systems. and do i need to make another partition with unallocated space or will one big data partition with probally 40g-50g free space suffice

For school/data I use DropBox and am able to play games from external HDD

And does Virtualbox need the same partitions as a Dual boot and provide the same problems?

I hope that anybody can help me with my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

For the hard drive part of the question, when doing things on a VM, you will make a virtual hard drive on the already existing file system. for example if you have windows as the host system, the virtual drive will just look like another file to windows, but in the VM it will be the hard drive for the VM. SSDs reallocate blocks as needed, so it shouldn't matter about the fact that the OS for the VM is running in all one file.

about you having 8gb of memory and not using a swap, that should work depending on how many programs/processes you have open. and remember that the Host machine OS and the Guest VM will both have to share the 8gb of memory, but how you divide that 8gb is up to you. If you want the full 8gb of memory to go to one OS, you might want to consider setting up your system as dual boot instead of using VMs.